# How can I freeze the first column and the first row with a scrollable table on R markdown?

Tags: html, css, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I would like to block the first row AND the first column in a `Kable` or `flextable` table on a Rmardown file  for html. The subject has already been discussed on SO but there is no answer. I don't want to use the DT package.

Maybe there would be a way to adapt the `scroll_box` function (`kableExtra` package)? Or to modify the concerned cells? I don't have HTML skills to do this.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creator of the `flextable` package added this option for html reports.
This does not exist on the `kableEtra` package or any other package as far as I know.

```
library(flextable)
dat <- lapply(1:30, function(x) rnorm(n = 50)) %>% 
  setNames(paste0("colname", 1:30)) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

ft_1 <- flextable(dat)
ft_1 <- set_table_properties(ft_1, 
                             opts_html = list(
                               extra_css = ".tabwid tbody tr > :first-child {position: sticky;z-index: 1;left: 0;background: #ddd;}",
                               scroll = list(height="500px")))
ft_1
```

https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/461